# VBA Script 424: object required on Selection.row.count

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Testrun()

Dim l As Long

l = Selection.Row.Count
ActiveCell.Value = l


End Sub
```

This code is showing 424 error: Object required in VBA. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use **Rows** instead of Row

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Testrun()

Dim l As Long

l = Selection.Rows.Count

ActiveCell.Value = l


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my Problem perfectly. This has helped begin learning VBA greatly.